# Load Column Names Without Pulling Data Again

Tags: powerquery, m, buffering

## Background

My Excel workbook compares two large datasets, as read from external files.  Let `Data_A` and `Data_B` be those queries, loaded to my worksheets as the tables **Data_A**

| a_1 | a_2 | ... | a_*n* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

and also **Data_B**:

| b_1 | b_2 | ... | b_*m* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I wish to extract their column names, and load those to the worksheet as the separate tables **Fields_A**...

```m
let
    names = {"a_1", "a_2", ..., "a_n"},
    result = Table.FromColumns({Source}, {"Field Name"})
in
    result
```

| Field Name |
| --- |
| a_1 |
| a_2 |
| ... |
| a_*n* |

...and **Fields_B**.

```m
let
    names = {"b_1", "b_2", ..., "b_m"},
    result = Table.FromColumns({Source}, {"Field Name"})
in
    result
```

| Field Name |
| --- |
| b_1 |
| b_2 |
| ... |
| b_*m* |

## Inadequate Solutions

### Reference in New Query

Obviously, I can simply reference `Data_A` and `Data_B` in new queries.

```m
let
    names = Table.ColumnNames(Data_*),
    result = Table.FromColumns({names}, {"Field Name"})
in
    result
```

Now I *do* [`.Buffer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/table-buffer) both `Data_A` and `Data_B` at the end of their *own* workflows, right before they are loaded to the worksheets:

```m
let
    dataset = ...
    output = Table.Buffer(dataset)
in
    output
```

Unfortunately, these queries *again* pull the entire `Data_A` and `Data_B` datasets from their own files.  Since these files are so large, **the simple `Table.ColumnNames()` query takes *forever*.**

### Read from Worksheet

Alternatively, I can read the data *back* from the **Data_A** and **Data_B** tables, which I just loaded to my worksheets:

```m
let
    sheetTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Data_*"]}[Content],
    names = Table.ColumnNames(sheetTable),
    result = Table.FromColumns({names}, {"Field Name"})
in
    result
```

Unfortunately, **this approach is unstable**, since the user may make manual edits to the table.  They may rename columns, delete them, and even add new ones!

## Question

I absolutely *must* load to my worksheets a list of the column names from each table **Data_A** and **Data_B**.  These names *must* reflect the *original* names loaded to the tables, *before* any manual edits by the user.  However, this info must *not* take forever to load—as they do when referencing `Data_A` and `Data_B`.

Is there a way to store the column names as an intermediate step in the `Data_*` query, and then load this step to a separate sheet, without restarting the `Data_*` query from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

## Beware of `Buffer`

I think in this case `Buffer` won't help. Does it really speed things up?

I imagine if you have "Data_A" and "Data_B" queries, and you don't buffer, then `Table.ColummNames` should pretty fast. Failing that, see if `Record.FieldNames(Table.First(Data_A))` is any faster. Power query is very lazy neither should cause all of Data_A to be read *unless* you buffer!

Maybe if it's a text file, you can pull just the first line in the file instead of first converting the data into a table?

## Users can modify sources they can modify

If you don't want to cache the data where it's possible to change it, you can't have it in a file they can modify.

When you talk about a cache within the workbook file, it means your users can modify it. So, if you can trust that users won't bother trying to hack stuff, you can cache to a hidden worksheet if that helps, but usually that means you need to guarantee that query is refreshed before your other queries are run and that makes your solution more fragile.

Dpending on your process you might decide it's better to have three external files:

1. Data_A source file
2. Data_B source file
3. An Excel workbook that pulls in the data tables *and* also writes the column names. This file could be automatically refreshed when either data source file is updated, and it can be the only external file your users: workbook needs to read.

I don't know if staging data in a workbook like this might work for you. It means an extra step because it "must* be reliably updated before your users try to access it. As a safeguard you could make a query in the workbook your users edit so that errors are thrown or bright yellow warnings appear if the modified date of the "staged data' workbook's is older than the Data_1 or Data_2 files it pulls from.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!  _"If you don't want to cache the data where it's possible to change it, you can't have it in a file they can modify."_  The business requirements of the workbook mean that **(1)** the **Data_A** table must be editable by the user; and **(2)** the **Fields_A** table must show the _original_ columns, with which **Data_A** was _initially_ loaded to the worksheet prior to any modifications by the user.

Comment: _"...see if `Record.FieldNames(Table.First(Data_A))` is any faster."_  Unfortunately, I suspect this won't quite work.  When supplied with the path to a _folder_, rather than a file, I have set up `Data_A` to [`.Combine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/table-combine) the datasets from the files within that folder.  Because `.Combine()` takes the _union_ of their columns, we can't reliably define a schema from just one file; we must first load and combine the datasets to yield the `output` for `Data_A`.

Comment: You can in theory create a function that accepts a filepath and returns the first row in that file. Applying that to each file in the folder shouldn't be too slow.

Comment: So are you setting it up and then users edit the workbook? Edit copies of it?

Comment: It's actually an Excel `.xltx` template, so each time it opens anew in a blank state.  The user must specify the file/folder paths before hitting "Refresh" to pull in the data.  Once that data is loaded, they may "Add table column" to define auxiliary columns, alongside the data that was just pulled.  I need **Fields_A** and **Fields_B** to help me distinguish the original columns from those added manually by the user.

Comment: _"You can in theory create a function that accepts a filepath and returns the first row in that file."_  I should note that I have a function `Import_Files(path, name, [sheet], [headers], [skip])`, which accepts the `path` to a file or folder, and reads either the sheet (`sheet = true`) or the table (`sheet = false`) called `name`.  When `sheet = true`, it optionally omits the first `skip` rows before processing, and optionally promotes the headers (`header = true`).

Comment: The user supplies the value for `skip`, so I can't rely on it always being the first row in the file.  It might be the first row in a _table_, but the table is positioned several rows down and several columns to the right.  Or it might be the 45th row in a sheet. When `sheet = true`, we'd need to load at least the first `skip + 1` rows.  **Long story short, we'd need to do a lot of the processing I've _already_ done on `Data_*`, simply to _identify_ the full set of column names in the first place.**

Comment: This is why I tried `.Buffer()`: in an effort to capture the final state of `Data_*` in memory, right before it was loaded to the sheet.  I thought it would be simple to get the `.ColumnNames()` of a table already stored in memory.  Am I misinterpreting `.Buffer()`?

Comment: _"...to capture the final state of `Data_*` in memory, right before it was loaded to the sheet."_  Alternatively, could I achieve this by loading my `Data_A` and `Data_B` to the **Excel data model**?

Comment: I don't think you are misinterpreting buffer, but the power query language is extremely lazy, queuing (instead of eagerly computing) as many operations as possible until the moment each value is actually necessary. Buffering computes and caches all values. (E g. `List.First(List.Numbers(Number Power(10, n)))` takes the same amount of time for any `n` because only the first value is computed anyway... but if you buffer that list....)

Comment: Are you saying that the data files are different per user and THEY tell your workbook what the formatting is??

Comment: _"Are you saying that the data files are different per user and THEY tell your workbook what the formatting is??"_  Correct: the user specifies the arguments in certain cells, and PowerQuery reads them as parameters: `Input_Name`, `Input_Path`, `Input_Sheet`, and `Input_Skip`; and the same four for `Output_*`.  Right now, I've kept `Input_Headers` and `Output_Headers` hardcoded as constants, but I might make them editable by the user as arguments.

Comment: Aside from memory/size limits in Excel, this template is designed to accommodate datasets of any schema whatsoever: a completely arbitrary set of column names; a complimentary set of auxiliary fields defined by the user; and a completely arbitrary subset of their union, used as keys to join the input/output record for validation.

Comment: _"the power query language is extremely lazy, queuing (instead of eagerly computing) as many operations as possible until the moment each value is actually necessary. Buffering computes and caches all values."_  I had hoped that buffering `Data_*`, just before loading it to the worksheet, would make it very quick to do `Table.ColumnNames(Data_*)` in another query, because PowerQuery need not pull and transform the `Data_*` a second time.  Might [`BufferMode.Delayed`](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2022/03/20/new-options-for-the-table-buffer-function-in-power-query) yield the best of both worlds?

Comment: As for folding and lazy loading, will PowerQuery still do that for a query whose `Source` step is generated by a custom function like `Import_Files()`?  This `Import_Files()` depends on another custom function `Process_Workbook()`, but neither of them use `Table.Buffer()`.

Comment: Re BufferMode.Delayed: I doubt it but I'd never heard of it until today. (Thank you!) Chris Webb [says](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2022/03/20/new-options-for-the-table-buffer-function-in-power-query/) it makes the UI feel faster when developing but it doesn't actually make the results come any faster.

Comment: As for the rest of your questions, I don't know.

Comment: _"As for the rest of your questions, I don't know."_  Well, thanks anyway for your time and advice!  If I could simply modify an existing variable in PowerQuery, so I can save the `list` of column names to a `#shared` variable within the `Data_*` workflow, then everything would be fine.  Unfortunately, I don't think M allows this.  So I've settled on a hidden "divider" column at the right end of the loaded table, which separates the query columns from any manual columns added subsequently by the user.  My `Fields_*` query uses this to identify which is which.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Table.ColumnNames on Table.FirstN then hopefully powerquery folding would be powerful enough to rapidly grab column names without pulling in the entire external file